# What is the difference between malloc array and regular array when in both I have to specify memory size?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

What is the difference between `malloc()`-ed array and regular array when in both I have to specify memory size, for example

```
char* arr =  malloc(50 * sizeof(char))
```

vs

```
int arr [50]
```

Comment: `char` and `int` are different types altogether...and you don't compare apples with oranges, anyways.

Comment: What do you mean - what is the difference?  Question unclear

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are too many differences. To start with, read about **[arrays are not pointers and vice versa](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)**.

That said, three major differences from the *usability* point of view (*which I feel you're interested about*)

- An array has a scope limited to its enclosing block, but dynamically allocated memories live unless deallocated manually. So, arrays local to a function cannot be `retrun`ed  but a pointer, returned via `malloc()`-ing , can be.
- For non-[VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) case, array size **must** be a compile time constant but for `malloc()` size is specified at runtime. In other words, for arrays, you need to know the size at compile time whereas, for `malloc()`-ing, it's perfectly possible to determine the requested size at runtime.
- Arrays cannot be re-sized. Once defined, they use all the memory required for their size. OTOH, a `malloc()`-ed pointer, pointing to some amount of memory, can very well be `realloc()`-ed to some other amount of memory, as needed.

Comment: Also, allocation failures can be detected by inspecting the return value from `malloc()` etc., but failure to allocate a static array or a VLA is undetectable AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

The chief difference is that dynamically-allocated memory can be resized as necessary; arrays (static, automatic, or variable-length) cannot be resized once they have been instantiated.

A secondary difference has to do with the array's *lifetime*.  Arrays declared at file scope or with the `static` keyword have lifetimes that extend over the lifetime of the program.  Arrays declared within a function or block *without* the `static` keyword have lifetimes that are limited to the extent of their enclosing scope (which is why you can't return a pointer to a local array from a function - the array *ceases to exist* when the function exits).

Dynamic memory falls somewhere in between - its lifetime extends from the initial `*alloc` call until the `free` call, which may be in different functions.  *You* control its lifetime directly.

Because of how memory is often managed for `auto` (local) variables, automatic and variable-length arrays often can't be arbitrarily large - attempting to create a local array that's more than a megabyte or so in size can lead to a runtime error on popular platforms.  You typically don't have such limits on dynamically-allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Because in array size should be available at compile-time, while using pointer let you determine at run-time the size of it.

Comment: Maybe you should add "non-VLA".

Comment: Yes but VLAs are just an option.

Answer (score 0):

From [this link](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation) :

Dynamic memory allocation allows your program to obtain more memory space while running, or to release it if it's not required.

In simple terms, Dynamic memory allocation allows you to manually handle memory space for your program.

[Here](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/dma.html) you can also read that in static allocation the required memory is allocated by the compiler and the exact size and type of storage must be known at compile time. On the other hand, in dynamic memory allocation, memory allocated "on the fly" during run time and the dynamically allocated space is usually placed in a program segment known as the heap or the free store.

Answer (score 0):

With the `malloc` the size you use can be a variable! That means the size could change depending on the change in the variable before execution reaches the `malloc` statement. Specifying the size of a declared array otherwise must be constant.

```
int foo = 5;
char bar[foo]; // This will cause a compile error
char bar[5]; // size is fixed, array size specifiers MUST be constant in C  

void some_func (void) 
{
    // do some work that might change foo, e.g. get a value from user

    char* arr =  malloc(foo * sizeof(char)); //foo is variable, thus the size is variable!
}
```

Note that you said you have said you use `malloc` to create an array. This is incorrect. `malloc` merely allocates some contiguous memory and gives you a pointer to the start of that memory - technically this is *not* the some thing as an array (it can be used as if it *was* in quite a few circumstances, but not *all* circumstances)

Comment: but can't I also get - for example -  an int from the user at run time and assign it to a variable (say x) and then declare an array arr[6]; ?

Comment: No, because the C language does not allow array lengths to be variable in this way. Using `malloc` instead in this case *is* allowed though

Comment: Actually you could do `char bar[foo]`

Comment: @ChrisTurner This does compile for automatic (function-scope) arrays but will cause error for global arrays.

Comment: So it does allow array lengths to be variable in some cases contrary to your previous comment ;)

Comment: Not so; from your snippet, foo is defined to what? If we say 5 then  this is the length assigned to the array on the stack when the function is called. Any subsequent changes to foo during execution will not change the length of the array